# How do i get files from a GIT repository in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, git, nsurlconnection

So I have files stores in a GIT repository.  Now I usually do a  `git pull` to get the latest revisions. Since the path to the file I wish to get is basically a URL like: https://github.com/.../myfile.extention, is there a way I can get the file in Objective C?

I know how to get data from a url using NSURL and NSURLRequest, but i'm not sure of the following:
1. GET ? or POST?
2. How do i authenticate?

I've searched on Google but gotten mostly results that give me some sort of frame work. Is there any way to do this in the simplest way without some extra framework?

`Update:` Some below have suggested I use the Git.Framework, but they do not as yet support remote pushing and pulling as seen below.

[image]

Does any one know how to pull and push a file from objective c code?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Git.framework](https://github.com/geoffgarside/Git.framework). It seems to be a proper tool for this task. From their website:

> The currently supported features of the project are
>
> - Reading objects, both loose and packed
> - Resolving refs from .git/refs
> - Reading branches, both local and remote
> - Enumeration of commits in breadth and depth first orders
> - Rev-list Support to a certain degree, full compatibility with git    rev-list is not yet available
> - Preliminary PACK File and Index generation support (API needs work,    deltas currently unsupported)

Comment: is there some way to do this without an extra framework? External frameworks cant be added to this project. The task is simple, get the data from a URL. The URL being a GIT repository link.. ?

Comment: Git.framework is open source, so if for some reason you can't use an external framework you could still look at their code and learn from it.

Comment: Im sorry, but i specifically asked for a simple code way of doing doing it because i'm new at this. The framework wont help me if i cant understand it.. that's why i'm asking here. Also, using a framework for such a simple task is a bit overkill right?

Comment: I'd also suggest that if you want a stripped down, minimalist solution, invest the time to figure out how Git.framework does the piece that you're interested in. Then just implement that piece.